# Redmine OSX or iOS interface

Tags: user-interface, project-management, redmine

Are there any quality OSX desktop and/or mobile clients which interface well with Redmine and provide more use ability than simply an ATOM or RSS feed?

I know that Redmine lists several desktop and mobile interfaces on their wiki but I've tried all of them for iOS and OSX and am not impressed.

I've been using Redmine for a while and love it, we just migrated everyone over to it today and I received numerous requests from the team for a desktop interface.

I found a project on GitHub which wasn't listed on the Redmine wiki and it was the best I'd tried, but was still rather useless.  Thought I'd check to see if anyone is working on this or if there may be a little known good client someone knows of.

Thanks

Comment: www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/ThirdPartyTools

Answer (score 1):

Check these links out for Redmine clients:

RedminePM - Redmine Client App
https://code.google.com/p/redmine-desktop-client

A simple and convenient way 
time tracking in Redmine
http://rmclient.org/

Redmine Client for iPhone / Android
http://redminepm.com/

Comment: All of the apps you listed are listed in the Redmine wiki which I explained in my question I have already tried.

Answer (score -1):

May be you could try building your own client. If you are comfortable with java you can start with this as a base. This code does basic time logging and creating tasks dynamically.
https://github.com/achennuru/redmine-client
Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that you have to state explicitly that this is your own site you're linking to: see [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).